# Does the OS (Ubuntu LTS vs CentOS) has a significant impact on the performance of a MySQL Server

Tags: mysql

In the following scenario:

- same hardware
- same mysql version
- same configuration settings
- same load
- using latest stable version of the OS

Does the OS has an impact on MySQL overall performance?
The customer's IT staff is advising on chaning Ubuntu LTS with CentOS to improve performance.

Am I missing something?

I would undestand the impact of a distro like Gentoo or Arch Linux, but not really CentOS.

Comment: I think it will be difficult for anyone to answer this without doing an apples-to-apples test. You should do your own testing where you use  the same version of MySQL with identical configuration settings not only of MySQL (my.cnf) but of the filesystem, etc. I would be very surprised if after all that effort to standardize if there was a significant performance difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Benchmark it and test for yourself...

You *will* find that the different operating systems may have different application-level defaults. So examine configuration files closely before deeming that everything has the *"same config"*.

The kernels are also different and have different OS-level default settings. Think about `sysctl.conf` settings, for instance.

Or think about how RHEL/CentOS 6 and newer systems have the [**tuned-adm framework**](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Performance_Tuning_Guide/main-analyzeperf-tuned.html) to set server performance profiles...

Comment: I agree with ewwhite. You should ask them on what basis CentOS could give mysql faster perfomances.
From what I know, performances differences are (in general) related to different kernel versions/patches, filesystems (and their mount options) and, of course, software versions (e.g. mysql 4 vs mysql 5).